# How to cut/paste multiple lines with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I assigned an `Alt+X` shortcut to `Cut Line` command in Eclipse.

On Windows, I can press `Alt+X` 3 times. When I paste (either in Eclipse or in another application), all 3 lines are yanked. I prefer this behavior.

On Ubuntu, after cutting 3 lines, the paste only yanks the last line.

How can I get consistent Eclipse behavior when cutting/pasting multiple lines on both Windows and Ubuntu?

I'm running Eclipse Kepler.